# Is there a way to have only specific extensions included in my workspace? (e.g., via a files.include or such?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
"files.exclude": {
      "**/*": true,
      "**/*.cs": false
    }
```

in order to include only .cs files in the workspace -- ignoring all other files (without me having to enumerate all the others)

Is there any way to do this currently?  files.include doesn't work, and the above excludes everything, the `"**/*.cs: false"` line doesn't override the previous glob.

Thanks much for any help :)